# How to run in local enviroment this solution SPFX on Sharepoint local enviroment

Tags: spfx

I find out some solutions on internet, but i don't know how run this solutions on Sharepoint local enviroment. [Here is a link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud).

Please help me.

Comment: I need arest api for spfx.

Answer (score 0):

To run and debug SPFx solutions on your local machine you use gulp serve.

There is a really good video walk through on developing your first SPFx project on youtube, you can find it here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension

Comment: But try with Thor extension. Its A lot od errors.

Comment: Can you specify what errors you are getting?

Comment: I',m getting this errors:
[15:20:23] Local gulp not found in C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Sharepoint_test\samples\sharepoint-crud
[15:20:23] Try running: npm install gulp

Comment: The gulp package has not been installed in your project. You'll need to navigate to the project folder and run `npm install gulp`. Without this package you wont be able to test your solution locally.

Comment: I tried this, but after this command I get: 
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Sharepoint_test\samples\sharepoint-crud\node_modules\.staging\office-ui-fabric-react-cc635fa8\lib\components\FocusTrapZone\index.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Sharepoint_test\samples\sharepoint-crud\node_modules\.staging\office-ui-fabric-react-cc635fa8\lib\components\FocusTrapZone\FocusTrapZone.d.ts'